# "decimal" - Data truncated for column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add some test values into my database, but I'm always getting this `Data truncated for column ...` error when I enter decimal values.

For example I'm trying to enter this:

```
INSERT INTO `offers` (`id`, `userid`, `amount`, `onebtc`, `price`, `discount`) VALUES (NULL, '6', '14,22', '0', '10,32', '1');
```

into this table:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kSXV.png)

Comment: use "." instaead "," in your decimal vaues

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to sending a decimal instead of a string??

```
INSERT INTO offers (id, userid, amount, onebtc, price, discount) VALUES (NULL, 6, 14.22, 0, 10.32, 1);
```

You're sending strings for everthing, so MySQL has to type cast it for you.